# Parsing in python for all pages of the site section

Tags: python, csv, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm making a python parser for the site: https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/series-top250/

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

CSV = 'genres.csv'
URL = 'https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/series-top250/?page=1&tab=all'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0', 'accept': '*/*'}


def get_html(url, params = None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='selection-film-item-meta selection-film-item-meta_theme_desktop')

    genres = []
    for item in items:
        additional = item.find_all('span', {'class':'selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item'})
        genres.append(
           {
                'genre': additional[1].get_text(strip = True)
           }
        )
    return genres


def save_genres(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(['genre'])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item['genre']])


def parser():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        genres = []
        for page in range(1, 6):
            html = get_html(URL, params = {'page': page})
            genres.extend(get_content(html.text))
            save_genres(genres, CSV)
        pass
    else:
        print('Non_available')


parser()
```

The section of site has 5 pages of rating:
https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/series-top250/?page=1&tab=all
...
https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/series-top250/?page=5&tab=all

I made a for_loop for parsing from all pages with changing number of page

```
for page in range(1, 6):
            html = get_html(URL, params = {'page': page})
            genres.extend(get_content(html.text))
```

but parsing occurs only on 1 page. Please tell me, what am I doing wrong?

And when I save the result in CSV, each line can contain more than 1 word (genre designation), I don’t know how to make sure that there is only 1 value on 1 line for aggregated analytics

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parameters from the URL (the part after `?` included):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

CSV = "genres.csv"
URL = "https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/series-top250/"
HEADERS = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0",
    "accept": "*/*",
}
PARAMS = {"page": 1, "tab": "all"}


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    items = soup.find_all(
        "div",
        class_="selection-film-item-meta selection-film-item-meta_theme_desktop",
    )

    genres = []
    for item in items:
        additional = item.find_all(
            "span", {"class": "selection-film-item-meta__meta-additional-item"}
        )
        genres.append({"genre": additional[1].get_text(strip=True)})
    return genres


def save_genres(items, path):
    with open(path, "w", newline="") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",")
        writer.writerow(["genre"])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item["genre"]])


def parser():
    genres = []
    for page in range(1, 6):
        print("Parsing page {}...".format(page))
        PARAMS["page"] = page
        html = get_html(URL, PARAMS)
        if html.status_code == 200:
            genres.extend(get_content(html.text))
        else:
            print("Non_available")
    save_genres(genres, CSV)


parser()
```

Creates `genres.csv`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Can you still help with breaking all words into 1 column?

Comment: @Daderk86 You can try `genres.extend(chain.from_iterable([g.split(",") for g in get_content(html.text)]))` (do `from itertools import chain` first). But since I'm getting captcha page, I cannot test it.